# user Account not creating in firebase android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am trying to make an account on my own app. but when I press the `signup` button app `gets closed` and `no data I found in the Firebase console.` i can't understand what is wrong with code.

> MainActivity.java

```
 package com.example.whatsapp;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.firebase.auth.AuthResult;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private FirebaseAuth auth;
    FirebaseDatabase database;
    TextView forgotpassword,phonesignup;
    Button Signup,Googlesignup,fbsignup;
    EditText Name,Password,email;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        forgotpassword = findViewById(R.id.forgotpassword);
        phonesignup = findViewById(R.id.phonesignup);
        Signup = findViewById(R.id.Signup);

        auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        database =FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        DatabaseReference myRef = database.getReference("message");

        forgotpassword.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent forgotintent = new Intent(v.getContext(), ForgotpasswordActivity.class);
                startActivity(forgotintent);
            }
        });
        phonesignup.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent =new Intent(v.getContext(),phonesignup.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
        Signup.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email.getText().toString(),Password.getText().toString())
                        .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()){

                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "account created", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                        }
                        else {
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        });


    }
}
```

> gradle dependencies

```
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.3.0'
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.4'
implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:27.1.0')
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:19.7.0'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.+'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.2'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0'
implementation 'com.airbnb.android:lottie:3.7.0'
```

> logcat error

```
04-21 17:25:13.270 29804-29804/com.example.whatsapp E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.whatsapp, PID: 29804
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.text.Editable android.widget.EditText.getText()' on a null object reference
        at com.example.whatsapp.MainActivity$3.onClick(MainActivity.java:56)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4788)
        at com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton.performClick(MaterialButton.java:1119)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19923)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5401)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:919)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:714)
```

Comment: If the app crashes, there is a stack trace. Please look that up on logcat, and add it to your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have't attach your EditText with your Xml

```
EditText Name,Password,email;// this need to be intialize.
```

Logcat says it all

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.text.Editable android.widget.EditText.getText()' on a null object reference
```

```
name = findViewById(R.id.<your_id_name_in_xml>);
```

do the above thing for password and email

Comment: You should mark the answer if it solved the issue.